Querying a single column from the Excel file using LangChain
I have a regular .xlsx file that has just a few columns:



Class
Name
Comments




1
Jack
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet


2
Mary
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet


2
Tony
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet


...
...
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet



I want to build a RAG based LLM with langchain so that user can ask questions about the 'Comments' column, such as what is the general theme of the comments?
The LLM should also be able to handle questions that requires filtering by name or class, for example, user may ask what is the general theme of the comments for Classs 1?
What components from LangChain would allow me to build such chatbot capabilities? I am particularly interested in the choice of document loader that could properly process tabular data in Excel and the ability to specify which column to query and which column to filter

convert the excel file to sqlite db.
create a sql agent pointing to that sqlite db.
you can create langchain agent query the db as you require.
Human language--> SQL query( select columns, filters, conditions) --> query execution--> results summary
